# k-Edge Shortest Path in Positive Weighted Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am given a graph, G = (V, E), that is positive weighted, directed, and acyclic.  I am to design an algorithm that runs in O(k(m + n)) for reporting a k-edge shortest path from s to t.  A k-edge shortest path is defined as a path from s to t with k edges and the total weight of the path must also be minimum for all paths from s to t.

Since BFS can't be used alone to find shortest paths (unless the weights are equal), I think that the running time implies using BFS to find paths with k edges.  What's throwing me off is the k, as I think it implies performing BFS k times.

My possible idea would be to run a BFS from the source to find all possible k-link paths.  By keeping track of the level along the way and storing the total path weight to each node when I add it to my queue, I can find all possible k-link paths and their weights. Obviously, if I encounter the destination at a lower level with lower path weight, there is no k-edge shortest path by definition.  What about cases where there are paths with more than k edges that are less total weight?  It also is not O(k(m + n)). Any helpful hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

Let `f[i][j]` be the i-link shortest path from `s` to `j`, initially we have

```
f[1][x] = e(s, x);
```

Then iterate `K - 1` times, each round we use `f[i][]` to compute `f[i + 1][]`, which can be done by

```
for each node v:
    f[i + 1][v] = INF;
for each edge e[u][v]:
    f[i + 1][v] = min(f[i + 1][v], f[i][u] + e[u][v]);
```

thus takes `O(k(n + m))`.

Comment: You also need to keep track of the path itself, not only its cost. A similar array parent[i][j] is needed (i:number of steps, j: destination node). While iterating over the edges (u,v), store the u that results in the minimum f[i+1][v]